# Converting a raster object to an im object in R

Tags: r, image, spatial, raster

I am trying to convert a raster object to an .im object for use with a point process model in the spatstat package in R. I begin by creating the raster from a tiff file using the raster() package. No problems there. I then proceed by cropping the raster according to a given extent. Again, no problem there. I then specify a spatial window (owin) defined using the same extent. Still no problems. When I then proceed to the final step of converting the raster to the im object using as.im(), the function runs and the new im object is created, but it has somehow lost the pixel information that was contained in the original raster such that each pixel now has the same value in the im object. Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks very much. 
The date file used is at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n67djm3n0tfa6sx/MGVF_2001_30_arc_sec.tif?dl=0 
And the R code is as follows:

```
library(raster)
library(spatstat)

# First set the geographic extent we'll be using
e <- extent(-20, 60, -40, 35)

# Then read in the Maximum Green Vegetation Fraction tiff and crop it
mgvf <- raster("MGVF_2001_30_arc_sec.tif")
mgvf.2001.africa <- crop(mgvf, e)

# Now let's create a window for in spatstat
SP.win <- as(e, "SpatialPolygons")
W <- as(SP.win, "owin")

# Finally, we create the .im object
mgvf.img <- as.im(X = "mgvf.2001.africa", W = W)

# Notice, there are no errors thrown. However, compare the plots below and see the loss of information:
plot(mgvf.2001.africa)
plot(mgvf.img)
```

Incidentally, I have tried the above as shown as well as trying to replace the NAs in the raster prior to converting to im. The result is the same. Thanks.

Comment: maybe first extract the data `matrix` from the `raster` object, then stick that matrix into `as.im` ?

Comment: It looks like you have been able to convert a raster image to a spatstat `im` object in another post (http://stackoverflow.com/q/26162955/3341769). Is this question still relevant?