# Converting raster (tiff) image to a pixel image in R - problems when converting spatial polygon into owin object class

Tags: r, image-processing, pixel, raster, gaussianblur

I am not an R expert, but i use it for all kinds of image processing. Now I am trying to apply Gaussian blur smoothing (spatstat package) on my satellite S-2 image. Original type of my image is Raster (Raster layer) tiff, actually a subtract image from two Sentinel-2 bands (green and blue). To apply blur on this kind of image I have to first convert it to a pixel image. I've tried doing this following few  other questions (like this one [Converting a raster object to an im object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980060/converting-a-raster-object-to-an-im-object-in-r)), but i did not succed. I have tried few possibilities, like converting raster image into matrix and than to pixel image, but this does not work, because the image is than too large (although I use small, croped area of the whole Sentinel-2 image).

So, my function in brief looks something like that:

```
blue <- raster("S2A_OPER_MSI_T33TWH_B02.tif")
green <- raster("S2A_OPER_MSI_T33TWH_B03.tif")

subt <- function(r1, r2) {
 return(r2-r1)
 }

out_sub1 <- (blue, green, fun = subt)
```

I tried to apply blur directly on a Raster image, but i soon realized its not working on raster data:

```
gauss_sub1 <- blur(out_sub1, sigma = 5) 
#Error: is.im(x) is not TRUE
```

So, I try to convert my image into a pixel one

```
out_sub11 <- as.im(X = "out_sub1")
Error in as.im.function(X, W, ..., dimyx = dimyx, na.replace = na.replace): A window W is required
```

Therefore I try to define a window following my raster extent

```
e <- out_sub1@extent
sp_w <- as(e, "SpatialPolygons")
W <- as(sp_w, "owin")
Error in as(SP.win, "owin") : no method or default for coercing “SpatialPolygons” to “owin”
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or how can I convert spatial polygon into owin object class, so I can further process blur command?

And can please someone explain me what difference there is between raster image and a pixel image in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter using `raster` library:

```
library(raster)
r <- blue - green

# 3 by 3 mean filter
r_mf <- focal(r, w=matrix(1/9,nrow=3,ncol=3))

# gaussian filter
gf <- focalWeight(r, 2, "Gauss")
r_gf <- focal(r, w=gf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Geo-sp. I forgot to mention before that I have used this approach for smoothing already (but using default function instead of Gaussean), and it works fine. I would still like to understand the question stressed above though.